# What to use instead window.location.href to call server method to show view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have event when user clicks on some link, the event has happen:

```
var dateParameter = "date=" + workday.DateString();                    
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "DateSelector")' + '?' + dateParameter;
```

I don't want to use this kind of call, because I want to hide parameters in URL of browser.

How can I do this? Is there is a way where I can use AJAX?

I have method in controller that look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string date)
{           
    // some logic...
    SomeViewModel vm = ...

    return View(vm);

}
```

If I use AJAX then it wont load the wanted page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dateParameter = "date=" + workday.DateString(); 

$.ajax({
        url: '/DateSelector/Index/' + dateParameter,
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It passes null for date in Contoller: public ActionResult Index(string date) {...}

Comment: Try passing the actual date string instead of dateParameter and see if it sends that to your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to pass it this way:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "DateSelector", 
                                              new { date = dateParameter })';
```

Let's mess around with the code a bit try:

```
var dateParameter = workday.DateString();

var text = "@Url.Action("Index", "DateSelector", new { date = "dateParameter" })"
text = text.replace("dateParameter", dateParameter);
window.location.href = text;
```

Comment: I want to hide parameters in URL of browser.